# Problem Locating and Changing Alt Attribute Of Link

Tags: customization

I'm a totally amateur so please dumb it down for me.

My WP them has a Social Links in the header of the theme and I want to change the Linkedin link link to a Pinterest link and change the Alt Attribute "View Our Linkedin Profile" to "Follow Us On Pinterest".

PROBLEM:
I can't find the text "View Our Linkedin Profile" that I want to change.  If I "View Source Code" in a browser I can see the text in the Source Code but I can't find the Alt text in any CSS files and I've been looking in my C-Panel's directory's files the best I can.

How do I locate the Alt Attribute, "View Our Linkedin Profile" to change the text if I can not find it in any of the CSS files?

Any help would be greatly appreciated and please, please really dumb down the answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which theme you use or which plugin we cannot really tell you much. Even if we knew what theme it is it would be hard as we may not know how the theme is coded.

What I can tell you is that the alt text on links is definitely not in any of the CSS files, as it's not what CSS files are for. You have to look in template or theme function files. If you have access to your server via FTP you could download the theme and run find command on the theme directory (some text editors offer an option to find a string in all files from directory). You will then know which file and line the text is located at.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.  I have looked in countless PHP files and I did actually look in the theme files in Windows and did a search for the text but I still could not access it.  Could it be in the database?  The theme is called Producto.  There is a live version here: http://themeforest.net/item/producto-wordpress-ecommerce-theme/full_screen_preview/2590881